# Problems with ngx-quill installation

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

Im having this errors while compiling my project

Error: node_modules/ngx-quill/lib/quill-editor.component.d.ts:3:21 - error TS2614: Module '"quill"' has no exported member 'Delta'. Did you mean to use 'import Delta from "quill"' instead?

3 import QuillType, { Delta } from 'quill';

---

Error: node_modules/quill-delta/dist/Delta.d.ts:1:8 - error TS1259: Module '"C:/ProyectoAgroSintesis/AgroCMS/node_modules/fast-diff/diff"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag

1 import diff from 'fast-diff';
~~~~

node_modules/fast-diff/diff.d.ts:20:1
20 export = diff;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag.

I dont know how to fix this, I installed quill following quill instructions in [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To resolve this error for **ngx-quill@16.2.1 and angular 13.1.2**, you need to ensure you install the correct version of @types/quill and quill

1. **@types/quill v1.x** -> npm i types/quill@1
2. **quill v1.x** -> npm i quill@1

Detailed installed instructions can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill)

Comment: thank you, I mas missing the `npm i @types/quill@1` that make it work without any other change.

Comment: thanks ! solved with ngx-quill@16.2.1 and angular 13.1.x

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same issue in angular 16.
For me I updated to the latest version of ngx-quill and quill
and I needed to install
[Yesterday 6:37 PM] Bikash Shah

**npm i @types/quill@1**

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know why I have this errors but I solve them

For the first error I change the imports in the quill-editor.component.d.ts like this:

```
import QuillType from 'quill';
import Delta from 'quill';
```

For the second error I put the flag `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` in my tsconfig.json in the compilerOptions

Also I change the version of the ngx-quill, I had the 16.1.2 and I downgrade to the 15.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by updating **tsconfig.ts** file to skip lib checks:

```js
{
// ..
"compilerOptions": {
        // ..
        "useDefineForClassFields": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        // ..
    }
 }
```